# The serial pin LVDSOUT for the LVDS SERDES IP instance must be pulled up to the top level and cannot fan out to anything else

Tags: ip, quartus

I have a compile error in my Quartus 20.3 project that appears to be within the Intel-generated LVDS SERDES IP.  Can you provide additional insight into what the following error indicates as root cause?  I believe the complaint is about a connection within the Intel IP:
"The serial pin LVDSOUT for the LVDS SERDES IP instance dsi2_host_phy_top|phy_wrapper|tx_dphy_top|clk_lane_altera|lvds_0|core|arch_inst|channels[0].tx.serdes_dpa_isnt must be pulled up to the top level and cannot fan out to anything else."

This LVDS IP instance is configured as TX, 1 channel, SERDES factor=8 with external PLL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a signal that comes out of that that SERDES IP block, specifically the `LVDSOUT` signal. The error is telling you that this signal cannot be connected to anything internal to your FPGA design. It can only be connected to the SERDES pin.

So for example, if you're trying to send the LVDSOUT pin to a flip-flop input, that could generate this error.

I would also recommend double-checking that the pin you're assigning to this signal is SERDES capable.

Comment: My scenario : while Transmitting, 1248(12x13x8) bits are bitsliced as 12x13x8 bits with the nested forloop structure and converted to 12x13 serial bits (i.e. 8:1 serialization). So 12x13 (156) bits are taken into a variable (wire of width (155:0)). From that variable data bits are assigned to I/O bank pins. So for my case the serial pins LVDSOUT shouldn't be fanned out. For that a macro should be defined and i am struggling to define the macro. So please help me how can i solve this issue.

Comment: @user18988222 it scares me a bit that you're using a for loop for any of this... do you know that a for loop expands replicated logic, it doesn't iterate something some number of times? https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-for-loop.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yeah that is how the code is, for loops are generating 156 serdes IPs each will do 8:1 serializations and the outputs are collected into a variable of width 156 bits.  From that variable the data are assigned to I/O pins. Is there any way that we can assign these 156 LVDSOUT output pins to a variable and then assign to I/O pins. Somewhere i found that we can define a macro so that these LVDSOUT pins are not considered as fanout pins.

Comment: What FPGA has 156 Serdes blocks? Virtex 7 goes to 96 on their highest grade part. That's quite a bit...